# How can I make a rounded corner grid?

Tags: wpf, border, rounded-corners

I tried and it sets a new border above the grid border:

```
<Window x:Class="Class.Window"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Window1" Width="379" Loaded="Window_Loaded"
        AllowsTransparency="True"
        ResizeMode="NoResize" ShowInTaskbar="False" Topmost="True" WindowStyle="None" Height="110">    
    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" CornerRadius="30,30,30,30">
        <Grid>
            <TextBlock Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="62,12,0,0" Name="textBlock_From" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="283" />
            <TextBlock Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="62,38,0,0" Name="textBlock_Subject" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="283" 
                       MouseLeftButtonDown="textBlock_Subject_MouseLeftButtonDown" MouseEnter="textBlock_Subject_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="textBlock_Subject_MouseLeave" />
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Window>
```

Comment: a grid itsself has no border at all, so either you put one inside or one around, like you did. As this question is not really clear, so far I could only reply: _like you did_

Answer (score 39, accepted):

As it is not entirely clear what you are trying to do, I guess you want a window with rounded corners and transparent background. Your solution is correct, you just have to set the `Window` background transparency and a background for the `Border`.

```
<Window x:Class="Class.Window"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Width="379" Loaded="Window_Loaded"
    AllowsTransparency="True"
    ResizeMode="NoResize" ShowInTaskbar="False" Topmost="True" WindowStyle="None" Height="110" Background="Transparent">    
    <Border Background="White" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" CornerRadius="30,30,30,30">
        <Grid>
            <TextBlock Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="62,12,0,0" Name="textBlock_From" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="283" />
            <TextBlock Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="62,38,0,0" Name="textBlock_Subject" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="283" 
                   MouseLeftButtonDown="textBlock_Subject_MouseLeftButtonDown" MouseEnter="textBlock_Subject_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="textBlock_Subject_MouseLeave" />
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Window>
```

Comment: How do you make a gradient background for the whole grid with rounded corners? This only works if the border has a solid color that is set as the same as the background.

Comment: Johncl you are absolutly right, if filling the gradient in border than grid background also filling transparency is not working.

Comment: When I set the background color in grid, it doesn't work. I don't understand why It does.

Answer (score 2):

A better solution is how the border and grid orders are defined in the XAML. For instance, this scheme works to mask the square grid corners underneath the rounded border and while the main grid is transparent:

```html
<Window x:Class="Class.Window"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Width="379" Loaded="Window_Loaded"
    AllowsTransparency="True"
    ResizeMode="NoResize" ShowInTaskbar="False" Topmost="True" WindowStyle="None" 
    Height="110" Background="Transparent">    

    <Grid Background="Transparent">
        <Grid Background="White" Margin="4">
            <!-- ...place functional control elements here... -->
        </Grid>

        <Border CornerRadius="12,12,12,12" BorderThickness="6" Padding="4">
            <!-- ...set your desired border brush color here... -->
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Great solution, thanks! One thing I ran into is the border blocked clicks on items underneath. Adding IsHitTestVisible="False" to the Border control resolved this. Just wanted to share in case someone ran into the same issue.